# Proguard: JNI call to JAVA method happens only once (instead of multiple times)

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, proguard, android-proguard

I have a problem with `Proguard` obfuscation. my (inline) java method is being called from the JNI only once, although it is called from a loop.

the first iteration of the loop runs well, but on the second one (`textureCount` > 1) the app seem not to enter the `getTexture` method - which causes my app to crash on `Texture::create(env, textureObject)` because `textureObject` is NULL.

To make it clear - **without `ProGuard` turned on - everything works fine**.

**In my JNI code**

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_MyApp_initApplicationNative(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj) {

    // Handle to the activity class:
    jclass activityClass = env->GetObjectClass(obj);

    jmethodID getTextureCountMethodID = env->GetMethodID(activityClass, "getTextureCount", "()I");
    if (getTextureCountMethodID == 0) {
        LOG("Function getTextureCount() not found.");
        return;
    }

    textureCount = env->CallIntMethod(obj, getTextureCountMethodID);
    if (!textureCount) {
        LOG("getTextureCount() returned zero.");
        return;
    }

    textures = new Texture*[textureCount];

    jmethodID getTextureMethodID = env->GetMethodID(activityClass, "getTexture",
                                            "(I)Lcom/example/MyApp/Texture;");

    if (getTextureMethodID == 0) {
        LOG("Function getTexture() not found.");
        return;
    }

    // Register the textures
    for (int i = 0; i < textureCount; ++i) 
    {
        jobject textureObject = env->CallObjectMethod(obj, getTextureMethodID, i);
        if (textureObject == NULL) {
            LOG("GetTexture() returned zero pointer");
            return;
        }
        textures[i] = Texture::create(env, textureObject);
    }

}
```

**proguard.cfg**

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-useuniqueclassmembernames

-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

# will keep line numbers and file name obfuscation
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

##########  default settings #########

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
    public void *(android.view.View);
    public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames,includedescriptorclasses class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.MyApp {
    native <methods>;
    int getTextureCount();
    com.example.MyApp.Texture getTexture(int);
}
```

**MyApp.java**

```
/**
 * Returns the texture object at the specified index.
 */
public Texture getTexture(int i) {
    return mTextures.elementAt(i);
}
```

**EDIT - SOLUTION**

the thing that solved this issue is probably that i didn't save the Texture class name via Proguard.
at first i used it this way, keeping just the relevant class members:

```
-keepclassmembers class **.Texture {
    native <methods>;
    byte[] getData();
    int mWidth;
    int mHeight;
    ....
    }
```

but when i changed it to:

```
-keep class **.Texture { *; }
```

it all worked out.
i must say that i'm not sure i can explain much, i just know that the return value from `getTexture()` and the `jclass textureClass = env->GetObjectClass(textureObject);` command, are now working perfect with no exceptions.

i'm trying not to use `-keep` as much as i can, but here i'm not sure i had a better solution.

Comment: `..com/example/MyApp/Texture..` .... you didn't save it from proguard ... and now it looks like `a.a.a`, poor class

Comment: The MyApp class is kept by another rule: -keepclasseswithmembernames ... native <methods>; }

Comment: Is the behavior the same when optimization is disabled?

Comment: @Neidhart what do u mean by saying it was kept by another rule?   ++  Yes. When using `-dontoptimize` it had same results. Only without `Proguard` it run correctly.

Comment: @T.Neidhart (-for referencing correctly) can you plz explain me what is the problem? i assume that is misunderstand some of the `ProGuard` deffenitions and meanings - which made one overcome the other. the main issue for me here is why does it enters the `JAVA` function on the first time, but not on the second one...

Comment: I can not explain the problem yet. Did you add logging to the native code, especially the value returned by getTextureCount()? My first guess was that ProGuard does some optimization there that breaks your logic, but as -dontoptimize does not make a difference it must be something else.